# ckeditor showing blank text area

Tags: 7, wysiwyg

I have been using ckeditor, with ckeditor drupal module with ckeditor 4.4.3 full edition. Previously, it was working fine and suddenly it was not working and it was showing blank text area in the body field as shown below.

[image]

I tried to re-install ckeditor module and library fields, but no change in the result. It appears empty, I couldn't trace the reason. How can I get to work with ckeditor.

Previously, my ckeditor was inserting span elements with a line-height of 1.6em in my paragraphs of text and I have no idea why.

The bottom shows body > p > span span span.  Spans with 1.6em line heights.

How can I resolve the issue??

Comment: Hello. Let me remind you that [Help center](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) forbids asking about *issues found in existing modules*. And if you believe it is not a bug in CKEditor, then please add more information to your question. What's the HTML structure of this form? Is text field there? JS loaded properly? Anything in watchdog or server's error.log? And so on.

Comment: There's an issue in the issue queue for the module on that, check out https://www.drupal.org/node/1853550

Comment: check you javascript console you're probably missing library files

Comment: I checked, no js files are missing. I noticed that when tried to open in another browser like safari, its working and in chrome, the problem is still there.

Comment: Use [jQuery Update](https://www.drupal.org/project/jquery_update) module and then please try to update the version of jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to clear cache, use jQuery update module to update the version of jQuery. This worked for me.

Wish it might help!!

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same issue. My issue was solved by completely removing the older files and adding new ckeditor files. And cleared both browser cache and drupal cache.
I was just overriding the files to the old Ckeditor folder , there was my issue.